# How do I configure an Azure APIM Oauth2 service for Azure AD B2C?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management

I'm exposing an API through Azure API Management. In order to call the API from the developer portal, an Authorization header with a bearer access token, issued by an Azure AD B2C instance, needs to be provided.

In the B2C instance, there is a signup/signin userflow (with connector API integration to load custom claims) that should be triggered by the APIM Oauth2 service configured for the API. This would mean that the user flow is triggered from within the developer portal (try it functionality) and the issued token is used to try out the API.

Who can point me in the right direction to get this working?

Remark: this is not an issue about setting up AAD B2C to get access to the developer portal, it is purely about calling our API from the developer portal (try it)  with a token issued by our aad b2c instance.

I already tried to configure the b2c authorization endpoint with the signup/signin policy passed as query parameter but without success. I would expected is needed to pass in the policy to be used to ensure the right policy is ran ...

Comment: Like this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad-b2c

Comment: It is not this (see my remark in the initial post). This is about how to authenticate against aadb2c to get access to the developer portal and is working fine. What I expect I need is an APIM Oauth2 service (OAuth 2.0 + OpenID Connect blade) that integrates with my API and gets triggered when the API is called using the 'try it' functionality in the developer portal.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you need to do to make this work.  First is setup an identity for AADB2C in the API Management (APIM) Portal folowing [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad-b2c).  It looks like you have already done this, but posting here for others.

[Identities section of APIM Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2H1N5.png)

The next thing you need to do is to setup the OAuth 2.0 user configuration within the APIM Portal by following [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad-b2c).

[OAuth 2.0 APIM Portal blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io3VA.png)

After you get these 2 pieces setup you will be able to login to the developer portal using AADB2C and then use the 'try it' functionality which will automatically put add the Authorization header once you select the flow from the developer portal.

[Developer portal 'try it'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/re4rQ.png)

There is a 3rd step that I would consider adding to actually force the apis to use the token that you are passing in.  This is by creating 'validate-jwt' policy in APIM to ensure you are validating that the request not only has a token, but it has a valid token.  You can get this info by following [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-api-management?tabs=app-reg-ga).

Hope that helps!